# How to specify standard input to Cevelop/EclipseC/C++ when running the program?

Tags: c++, eclipse-cdt, cevelop

I currently have the input file hard coded in the C++ code:

```
     constexpr auto SELECTED_COLLEGES {"rva-ceeb-working.txt"};
     std::ifstream ifs {SELECTED_COLLEGES, std::ios::in};
```

I intend to change the code to use standard input instead. When I run the program from the command line I will specify the file as:

```
     $ aptcp <rva-ceeb-working.txt
```

How do I tell Cevelop/EclipseC/C++ that when it runs the program to use `rva-ceeb-working.txt` for standard input?

```
Cevelop C++ IDE
Version: 1.8.0-201707131430

Eclipse C/C++ Development Tools
Version: 9.3.0.201706122201
Build id: @build@

Eclipse Help
Version: 2.2.100.v20170612-0950
Build id: I20170612-0950

OS: Linux, v.4.10.0-37-generic, x86_64 / gtk 3.22.11
```

Comment: If you are going to pipe input to your program you would use `std::cin` instead of `std::ifstream`, the latter is to read from disk

Comment: @CoryKramer does that "tell Cevelop/EclipseC/C++ that when it runs the program to use rva-ceeb-working.txt"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run > Run Configurations... > Common > Input File

[image]